# when std::less<char>{} is called by an invalid comparator I tried to implement my own function but not how,

Tags: c++, c++17

```
     template <typename It, typename F>
     pair<It, It> gather(It first, It last, It gather_pos, F predicate)
     {
         return { std::stable_partition(first, gather_pos, not_fn(predicate)),
         std::stable_partition(gather_pos, last, predicate) };
     }
     
     template <typename It, typename F>
     void gather_sort(It first, It last, It gather_pos, F comp_func)
     {
         auto inv_comp_func([&](const auto & ... ps) {
             return !comp_func(ps...);
             });
         std::stable_sort(first, gather_pos, inv_comp_func);
         std::stable_sort(gather_pos, last, comp_func);
     }
     
     int main()
     {
         auto is_a([](char c) { return c == 'a'; });
         string a{ "a_a_a_a_a_a_a_a_a_a_a" };
     
     
         auto middle(begin(a) + a.size() / 2);
         gather(begin(a), end(a), middle, is_a);
         cout << a << '\n';
     
         gather(begin(a), end(a), begin(a), is_a);
         cout << a << '\n';
     
         gather(begin(a), end(a), end(a), is_a);
         cout << a << '\n';
     
         // Это работает не так, как вы того ожидаете
         gather(begin(a), end(a), middle, is_a);
         cout << a << '\n';
     
         string b{ "_9_2_4_7_3_8_1_6_5_0_" };
         gather_sort(begin(b), end(b), begin(b) + b.size() / 2,std::less<char>{});
         cout << b << '\n';
     }
```

I implemented my own comparison function instead of less but it still doesn't work ,I studied the book and wrote this code from the author, everything worked, I looked for the answer in the stack is overflowed but I didn’t find it, maybe I was looking bad, I’m a newbie, if anything

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sort, we need a function that performs a strict comparison ( `compar(a,a)` must be false). Your `inv_comp_func()` is not strict, it is equivalent to `>=`.

You can use in place

```cpp
auto inv_comp_func([&](const auto &a, const auto& b) {
        return comp_func(b,a);
    });
```